# Couchbase N1QL: Retrieve documents that do not have a specific field

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have many documents in a bucket as

```
{ prop1: value, prop2: value, prop3: value}
```

But some documents do not have the prop3 field.

How can I retrieve all documents that DO NOT have the prop3 field, using an n1ql query?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `IS MISSING` keyword is your friend here:

```
SELECT * FROM bucket WHERE prop3 IS MISSING;
```

Comment: If someone is trying to do the opposite , NOT missing also works